# Hiding an element after clicking outside in vue 2

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I'm trying to hide a sidebar after clicking outside using Vue 2 and laravel. This sidebar was created inside a navbar component. At first, I added a `@click="showSidenav = !showSidenav"` just to open it and initialize data to `showSidenav: false`. And also added a close anchor tag to hide the sidebar. Working fine actually but when the thing comes in my mind that how about hiding it also when clicking outside the sidebar? I created a method `showSidenav` and perform the opening of the element and tried to use `nextTick` but it executes same time as when I call the method. For now I use jquery inside the method to change again the data but when I click again the hamburger menu it won't change the data.

[template structure](https://jsfiddle.net/rbocfhq9/)

```
<a href="#" v-on-clickaway="away" @click="openSidenav">Hamburger menu</a>
```

Script

```
 import { mixin as clickaway } from 'vue-clickaway';
    export default {
         mixins: [ clickaway ],
         data() {
             return {
                 showSidenav: false,
             }
         },
         methods: {
             openSidenav: function () {
                 this.showSidenav = true
             },
             away: function () {
                this.showSidenav = false
             }
         }
    }
```

> EDIT: Added `vue-clickaway` as suggested by @Nathan.

Comment: Why are you mixing dom manipulations and vue.js ? Totally feasible without jQuery lol.

Comment: @WilomGfx, yea lol and I hate why I wrote it that way :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had this problem. Use [vue-clickaway](https://github.com/simplesmiler/vue-clickaway).

Their 'hello world' example:

```
import { mixin as clickaway } from 'vue-clickaway';

export default {
  mixins: [ clickaway ],
  template: '<p v-on-clickaway="away">Click away</p>',
  methods: {
    away: function() {
      console.log('clicked away');
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Hey! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Tried it but no luck. This is how I set the data `away: function () {
         this.showSidenav = false
      },` the thing is it fires same time as I call the openSidenav

Comment: Can you include your template code in your question? It'll help me get a better feel for how you have things set up.

Comment: Already updated above post. I installed it using npm by the way.

Comment: Can you post the entirety of your `<template>` code? Where is the part of your template where you attach `v-on-clickaway="away"` to an element?

Comment: Added it inside the hamburger anchor tag.

Comment: Since it closes the side-nav, don't you think `v-on-clickaway="away"` should be on the side-nav rather than the button that opens it? Can you show what that part of your template looks like?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that template; it should be working. Are there any errors being printed to the console?

Comment: Do you have [Vue Devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en) installed? Can you see if `showSidenav` is changing when you click away? Can you paste the full contents of your .vue file in the question?

Comment: Too long to paste it here. I'm afraid

Comment: Ok I was really curious, so I looked at it and essentially the problem is that as soon as you click on the link that sets `showSidenav` to `true`, you are simultaneously triggering the `away()` function which is then setting `showSidenav` to `false`. The solution is to wrap both elements in a wrapper `div` and put the `vue-on-clickaway` on that wrapping element. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rbocfhq9/1/) is a JSFiddle which shows it working.